# Articles Details Page Carry

Tags: asp.net

I have articles stored in a database. I want to click on a heading and open the appropriate article in another page on a jQuery Mobile site. The following was my alogorithm of thinking:

1. Find **ID** of article
2. Pass **ID** to the #news-article page
3. Display the article where **Heading** and **Body** share the same **ID**

I should also note that I am using a Repeater to display my article on the page:

```
    <!--list article headings and date-->
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
    <a href="#news-body.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID") %>">
    <h3><%# Eval("Heading")%></h3>
    <p><%# Eval("Date")%></p>
    </a>
    </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>



 <!--the details (article body) page showing-->
    <script runat="server">
Partial Class page2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
</script>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

I'm a bit stuck here and am seeking some tutorials because I'm new to ASP and .NET. I'm not quite sure what this concept is even called just yet to get good search results. I would appreciate any help you may have to offer. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Once I start coding my page2, I get errors. Removing the code in page2 allows me to see the headlines in page1; however, it does receive an error loading the page (to be expected). Is my script even in the correct location for page2? Does that have to be in the <head>? I'm creating this in jQuery Mobile with navigation using ajax, so I am linking pages with #anchors...

Answer (score 0):

Try this slight tweak on building your `<a>` tag? It's just that you've got to concat your ID to a string of your URL.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
         <a href='<%#"news-body.aspx?id="+Eval("ID") %>'>
            <h3><%# Eval("Heading")%></h3>
            <p><%# Eval("Date")%></p>
         </a>
    </li> 
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I tried tweaking the <a> tag; but unfortunately, it didn't fix any error. I receive an error that reads: "Lable1.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() requires an object reference."  I'm not clear about what this means...

Comment: Not sure if it makes a major difference here, but I am using VB, not C#

Comment: Scratched this whole concept and got my ID passing. Just stuck with the data on details page not showing...Been following this tutorial if interested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530323.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. Looks like I needed some space away from coding to regroup my eyes. It was the little details in the datasource giving me a hard time and finding WHERE the id is identified and passed over. Thank you all for your help.